# How to run bootstrap.py to setup Firefox code base?

Tags: python, firefox, codebase

[image: Then I received this error.]

I followed the steps  provided [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Developer_guide/Build_Instructions/Mac_OS_X_Prerequisites). I ran `python bootstrap.py`, it prompted me to enter a choice, I entered 2, Firefox for Desktop Artifact mode.

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The guide you linked reports 2 important things:

1. Python **must** be version 2.7.11 (and you're using 2.7.13).
2. The script *can* error out if you already have Homebrew/MacPorts

The first problem can be solved, as reported by the guide, by using [pyenv](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv).

The second problem should be fixed by updating the Homebrew environment:

```
brew update && brew upgrade
```